# Tying someone up in 4E

Tags: dnd-4e

Is there any mention on how to tie someone up using a rope or chains in 4E? Let's say I have a sleeping player (helpless) and I try to tie him up. How does that work? What about a guy I just grabbed?

Comment: I don't believe binding is mechanically supported in 4e.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The thievery skill is used to bind someone with rope. The result of the check sets the escape DC for the person trying to escape with acrobatics.

It's not covered in a lot of detail, but it is mentioned under the thievery description:

> **[IMPROVISING WITH THIEVERY](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/skill.aspx?id=23)** 
>    - Fix a broken wagon (easy DC) 
>    - Craft a standard lock (moderate DC) 
>    - Bind a creature with rope (check result sets escape DC)

If the target is helpless, you can probably bind them easily. Binding someone you have grabbed though is much more difficult and isn't covered by the rules. I would probably disallow it completely or set up an opposed roll (Thievery vs. Acrobatics) skewed heavily in favor of the defender.

Comment: Good answer, and I have to agree.  Binding someone who's fighting back should be good for a -10 penalty on the check, even if they're not a better wrestler than you.

Comment: @Tynam -10 might be too generous

Comment: @waxeagle: On serious thought, you're right.  Having any chance at passing that check ought to involve *massive* level advantage, martial arts superiority, or the like.
(In earlier editions, of course, it would be even harder than that.  The attacker would need to understand the Grapple rules.)

Comment: I'd probably go with -20 on the attacker's thievery check, by default, with varying degrees of lesser penalties if the target is dazed/stunned/restrained/prone/etc.

Comment: If the attacker is trained at this kind of thing, it's not that hard to do.  Look at roping cows as an example (ok, the cow isn't intelligent, and isn't actively fighting off the roper, but it certainly is struggling).  "roping" an intelligent fighting target should probably fail more often than that, but roping cows works almost every time for a trained pro.  I'm not saying just anyone can do this easily, but when trained in the right techniques, it is not that difficult a thing to do (there's a whole study on the techniques used by Japanese police to do this).

Comment: @Ryno I have no argument from a simulationist perspective with it being relatively easy. 4e's inherent *balancist* perspective is the problem. Allowing a heroic tier character to effectively nullify a combatant for even 1 (save ends) rounds is a daily power for a rogue (knockout is a L9 daily). For them to be able to take them out for an entire combat would be a powerful skill. I have no argument that it's doable.

Comment: As a rules lawyer, it doesn't say binding a creature is done out of combat, or even that they need to be prone :-)

Comment: The rule also implies there is no Dc to succeed in binding, just how good the.binds are.re

Comment: Interesting comments but I think they should be moved to the chat room.